# How to get values into an array with row,column notation

Tags: google-apps-script

here is my script which works when the getRange is in a1 notation but when in row column notation the last column of the range is pulled into the  first column and no other data is in the array.
If this is a known problem how do you represent "A6:M8" programmatically to include the number of rows.   The // source line does not work and I fail to make it intelligent!

```
  function Copy() {
  var lp=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LP").activate();
  var sourceRows = lp.getLastRow();
   var source = lp.getRange('A6:M8').getValues();
    // var source = lp.getRange(6, 13, (sourceRows-5), 13).getValues();
var tr= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TR').activate();
  var trRows = tr.getLastRow();
   //var trput = lp.getRange('A234:M236').setValues(source);
     var trput = tr.getRange((trRows+1), 1, 3, 13).setValues(source);
};
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `sourceRows`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the last row in sheet LP is row 8, then your calculation of `(sourceRows-5)` should be okay. (Also assuming that you always want to copy 3 rows at a time.)

The problem is that you've entered `13` as the starting column of the range. Instead, that line should read

```
var source = lp.getRange(6, 1, (sourceRows-5), 13).getValues();
```

Two other suggestions:

1. You get the active spreadsheet twice. Place it into a variable so you don't need to do that. `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`
2. There seems to be no need to make the `activate()` call on the individual sheets, so consider removing.

Then you'd have something like this:

```
function Copy() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lp = ss.getSheetByName("LP");
  var sourceRows = lp.getLastRow();
  var source = lp.getRange(6, 1, (sourceRows-5), 13).getValues();
  var tr= ss.getSheetByName("TR");
  var trRows = tr.getLastRow();
  var trput = tr.getRange((trRows+1), 1, 3, 13).setValues(source);
};
```

Comment: Why stick to forcing a double-update if the size of `source` changes? `trput` should be `(trRows+1), 1, source.length, source[0].length)`. (And optionally guarded by an `if` statement, e.g. `if (source && source.length && source[0].length)`)

Comment: Good catch @tehhowch